# Avoid temp-file when adding a property to a PDF file in bash script

Tags: bash, pdftk

The following script makes use of a temporary file "data.txt" to which something is appended before reusing it. (Actually I simply add some metadata to a PDF)

```
#!/bin/bash

PDFTK="/app/bin/pdftk"
#PDFTK="pdftk"

$PDFTK $1.pdf dump_data output data.txt

cat  >> data.txt << EOF
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Myproperty
InfoValue: Myvalue
EOF

$PDFTK $1.pdf update_info data.txt output $1-$2.pdf
```

Both dump_data and update_info can write/read from stdout (see man pdftk)

bash-gurus: How can I rewrite the code such that no file is created ?

pdftk-gurus: Is there a better way to *add* a key/value pair?

Thanks, Bastl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is using `bash`, you may use a process substitution:

```
"$PDFTK" "$1.pdf" update_info <( "$PDFTK" "$1.pdf" dump_data output; cat <<EOF
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Myproperty
InfoValue: Myvalue
EOF
) output "$1-$2.pdf"
```

To the `pdftk` utility, the `<( ... )` argument will be treated as a file containing the output of the first `pdftk` call followed by the contents of the here-document.

Also note that you should be quoting your variables (see "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)").

Comment: Thanks for that. please note that the first pdftk actually writes the data.txt in the first place. I concat to it using the HERE document. I imagine it quite ugly to have the first call to pdftk (with dump_data to stdout) and concat with "cat" inside a  <(...)  ?? (I also have problems running that in my windows bash, but that is probably a local problem)

Comment: @Bastl I missed that bit. If `pdftk` writes to standard output by default, then my updated answer may work. It's not pretty, and honestly, I would probably go with using a temporary file.

Comment: Works like a charm on my webserver. Sadly not under mingw64 on my development windows machine. The anonymous filehandler does not work ...